# How to sort 2D array in kotlin according to it's column using comparator & lamda function?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, sorting, multidimensional-array, lambda

I want to sort 2D array in Kotlin, I know how to do it in java but it is not working in Kotlin, there must be a different syntax. I surfed on the internet but couldn't find a direct syntax solution.

I am creating a random 2D array and I want to sort it with respect to it's 3rd column.

```
fun main(){
        val rows = 3
        val cols = 4

        val arr = Array(rows) { r -> IntArray(cols) { c -> r + ((Math.random()*9).toInt()) } }
        for (row in arr) {
            println(row.contentToString())
        }
// I want to sort here
// In Java I would do this: Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingDouble( o -> o[2] ))
}
```

How to do the same in Kotlin, in Java I can sort it in the following manner:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingDouble( o -> o[2] ))
```

How to do the same in Kotlin syntax?

Comment: `arr.sortBy { o -> o[2] }` or just `arr.sortBy { it[2] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method `sortBy` will allow you to return the selected sorting criteria.

```
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt

val rows = 3
val cols = 4

val arr = Array(rows) { r -> 
    IntArray(cols) {
        r + Random.nextInt(1..5) * 9
    }
}

fun printArr() {
    for (row in arr) {
        println(row.contentToString())
    } 
}

printArr()
arr.sortBy { it[2] }
printArr()

// Generated:
// [36, 45, 45, 45]
// [19, 37, 28, 19]
// [11, 38, 11, 38]

// Output:
// [11, 38, 11, 38]
// [19, 37, 28, 19]
// [36, 45, 45, 45]
```